# Six Boys, Six Girls. How many possible partners?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling to understand the solution to this question concerning combinatorics.

**Question:**

At a party six boys and six girls dance together. Assuming that classical
dance is performed, in which one couple = one boy and one girl, how many possible
couples can perform together?

**My Solution:**

There are 6 boys. Each boy can dance with 6 girls. Label the boys $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

Boy $a$ can dance with 6 different girls.

Boy $b$ can dance with 6 different girls.

...

Boy $f$ can dance with 6 different girls.

Therefore, there are $6\times6\times6\times6\times6\times6=6^6=46656$ possible couples. (End of my solution)

**The Solution**

Fix an enumeration of the six girls and consider all their possible partners.
This is equivalent to permuting the boys, so each girl will dance once with each boy, i.e.,
the total number of possible dancing couples is

$$6!=720$$

(End of solution)

I don't understand:

(i) why my solution is incorrect.

(ii) why the solution provided is correct.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In your situation, all six boys could pick the same girl, but this is nonsense. The first boy has 6 choices, the second boy has 5 choices (since he cannot pick the chosen girl), and so on.

Comment: So...

Boy $a$ can dance with 6 girls.

Boy $b$ can dance with 5 girls. (Because boy a has a partner)

...(repeat the $n-1$ logic)...

Boy $e$ can dance with 2 girls.

Boy $f$ has the remaining girl.

So there are $6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1=6!$ possible couples?

Comment: Line up the girls line up in order of student number. There are $6!$ ways the boys can be lined up, hence $6!$ ways to divide the $12$ into mixed sex couples.

Comment: As a note here: Your way of thinking was also intuitively correct, given the wording of the question. It does not state that only one dance is performed - It could have possible multiple dances were held with differing partners, in which case $6^6$ would be correct.

Comment: Yes Shrimspy, that is exactly how I interpreted the question!

Comment: The key term was "perform together", which implies simultaneity.

Comment: The question is really badly stated (not the posters fault). I would say the answer is clearly six, because you'd need at least 14 people for seven or more couples. The OP's answer isn't wrong either, because there are indeed 46656 possible couples who can dance together. The answer 720 is clearly wrong, because it omits the possibility of 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 or no couple actually dancing. For a maths question we shouldn't have to divine what problem we are expected to solve.

Comment: Does it make me a bad person that I thought of something entirely different when I read the problem statement? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think people are failing to address the following issue with you're argument: there is an implicit requirement that all the couples be formed simultaneously. You're thinking about it quite right, except you're forgetting that once a girl has a partner she isn't available for the next boy.

Comment: Yes, I think this was exactly my problem!

Answer (score 1):

## Hint

all choices= all choices of the first boy $\times$ all choices of second boy $\times \cdots$
$=6\times 5 \times4\times3\times2\times1$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the pair, boy $b$ with girl $g$ denoted by $(b,g)$ is the same as the pair $(g,b)$. We approach this problem by placing the girls in the odd positions of a $12$ slot line, as in (assuming $(g_i,X_i)$ form a pair)

$$(g_1,X_1,g_2,X_2,g_3,X_3,g_4,X_4,g_5,X_5,g_6,X_6)$$

Now we want to determine the possible locations of boys $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_6)$ in the $X_i$ positions of the above vector. How many ways can we arrange $6$ objects in $6$ positions? We can arrange them in $6!$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the model (_, _, _, _, _, _), where each blank is a girl. We have 6 boys, and we place one distinct boy on a line. So there are $6!$ ways to arrange the boys. Look at this as a function, alternatively. Let $f: B \to G$, where $B$ is the set of boys and $G$ is the set of girls. How many bijections are there from $B \to G$? There are six ways to choose a girl for the first boy. There are five ways to choose a girl for the second boy, etc. So we get $6!$ as the answer.